# What Stack Exchange site to ask a math question on?

Tags: discussion, support, site-recommendation

Which is the most appropriate site to ask for how to get an answer for a mathematics problem that I don't know the formula to?

E.g., a very, very simple example to demonstrate what type of problem I mean,

How would I go about getting the answer for 100 divided by 10?

Obviously the answer would be 100/10 = 10

Is there a site that would cater to these kind of questions?

Answer (score 0):

You can go to [Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/) but make sure to check their [help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help) first to make sure your question is fit for the site.